# jQuery - Turn.js to use ONLY the page Peel effect

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css, jquery-plugins

Im trying to only get my code to use the peel effect that comes with `turn.js` where when the user hovers over the bottom right corner of the page the corner peels a little and looks like its bending up.

I do not want the actual turning of the page effect, just the peel effect .

According to the docs it says that I can do something like:

```
  $("#flipbook").turn({peel: "br"});
```

but it doesn't do the effect.

Here is the link to my jsfiddle I'm working on:

http://jsfiddle.net/A9a7E/5211/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `turning` event, and prevent the turn from actually happening. That, combined with adding a second page (so there's pages to actually turn, thus activating the effect) will give you the effect you're after -- a peelable corner without any actual page turning.

```
$("#flipbook").bind("turning", function(event, pageObject, corner) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/A9a7E/5215/

Within the event handler, you can there trigger your own reaction to the start of page turning, such as loading a new page or whatever you have in mind.

---

**edit**

As mentioned in the comments by dc5, you can manually trigger the peel method (as you are showing in your question) AFTER you've initialized it correctly. Here's a modification of the above sample with an added line to show the peel-down right away: http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/A9a7E/5216/ -- thanks dc5!

**Documentation**

- Event::turning - http://turnjs.com/docs/Event:_turning

Comment: doh!  of course why didnt i think of that!!  thats great thank you for the help

Comment: +1 - I believe the error was due to not calling the constructor function first.

Comment: If you look at his example fiddle, he's not passing the options correctly, so that's one issue (he does have it sort-of right in his question, but not in the fiddle). The other issue is that there was only one page in his sample. If you mess around with it, you'll see that it just does nothing unless there are multiple pages in the target element. Glad I could help, Ricky, good luck :)

Comment: You can use `$("#flipbook").turn("peel", "br");` [Doc for Peel method](http://www.turnjs.com/docs/Method:_peel), but only after properly initializing it.  In the provided fiddle, the library was never initialized and there was an error in the console (The OP mentioned it not doing the effect).

Comment: Ah, gotchya. Edited answer to include that.